# Updates to DOM not visible during CPU intensive WASM call

Tags: javascript, dom, webassembly, emscripten

Have a WASM program that takes ~12 seconds to run on my machine. To keep the user on the site, it'd be nice to indicate that the program is making progress. I inserted some calls using `EM_ASM_(...)` in the C++ WASM code to a JS function that's equivalent to:

```
function updateStatus(number) {
  console.log("status: ", number);
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Status: " + number;
}
```

While the console gets live updates, the "status" DOM element is not updated until the WASM code finishes.

I tried adding `sleep(1)` after the `updateStatus()` call in the C++ code, but that didn't lead to an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following C code seems to work, though there's a separate issue noted below:

```
EM_JS(void, updateStatus, (int number), {
  Asyncify.handleAsync(async() => {
    await Promise.resolve()
    .then(function() {
      console.log("status: ", number);
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Status: " + number;
    });

    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 50));
  });
});

void myWASM() {
  ...
  for(int number = 0; number < MAX; number++) {
    ...
    updateStatus(number);
    ...
  }
  ...
  printf("done with myWASM()");
}
```

The updates didn't appear live without the `Promise/setTimeout` call at the end, but this may be a general feature of DOM updates?

An oddity is that the `cwrap`'d to `myWASM()` returns to the JS caller *before* "done with myWASM()" executes. Seems like the `myWASM()` call is now asyncronous? Going to post a separate question on this.

Thanks to @sbc100 for suggesting ASYNCIFY.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript runtime yields to WebAssembly, which explains why the UI is not updated. To achieve what you are after you need to run your code in a Web Worker.

Comment: Indeed.   Alternatively, you could break up your task in chunks.. Or use ASYNCIFY to yield mid-task.